# Extjs 5 GroupGrid Capabilities (MVVM)

Tags: extjs, mvvm, extjs5

Hijust want to ask if Extjs Group grid have capabilities on displaying row data to other grid/window upon  click on the main groupgrid instead of displaying by collapsible on the same grid, sorry I haven't created my own codes yet I just want to ask ideas if this is possible.

for example

[image]

main grid contains top providers records sorted by 'utilcost' upon clicking the record, another window/grid will pop up to show all the records under the clicked provider. By the way Im using MVVM architecture.

Thanks any answer or ideas will be gratefully appreciated.|
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible : listen to the itemclick event. The callback function takes the record as argument.
Look at the doc http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/?mobile=/api/Ext.panel.Table#event-itemclick

Comment: Hi Lorenz I know this is too much, may I ask for a simple sample code so I can get some idea? Thanks